# Can't removing cells with splice when a new array contain exist array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this array:

```
var persons = ["jon", "jake", "logan", "april", "jean"];
```

and I want put in a new array the first two and last two names.

If I do this, splice work:

```
persons.splice (2,persons.length-4);
```

But If it's in new array it's give me exact the opposite:

```
var persons1 = persons.splice (2,persons.length-4):
```

Plus: what fuction can I use without "ruin" the first array.
Thank you very much !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could slice the array and build a new one with parts from start and end of the given array.

[`Array#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) does not mutate the array.

```js
var persons = ["jon", "jake", "logan", "april", "jean"],
    result = [...persons.slice(0, 2), ...persons.slice(-2)];

console.log(result);
```